# AbstractMethodError: gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EUtilsServiceStub

Tags: web-services, serialization

Everyone, I'm a fresh man in building webservice applications. I am using [this example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/soap/v2.0/DOC/esoap_java_help.html) to access the NCBI (National Center for Biotechnology Information) webservice API. But I am getting the error below when I try and access the data.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EUtilsServiceStub$EGqueryRequest.serialize(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter;)V
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource.serialize(ADBDataSource.java:90)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:695)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:563)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:874)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EUtilsServiceStub.run_eGquery(EUtilsServiceStub.java:1578)
    at edu.yale.pubmed.service.Client.CallEGQuery(Client.java:26)
    at edu.yale.pubmed.service.Client.main(Client.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the generated files in the axis2 folder, it can run sucessfully. The only result is it automatically an implemented EUtilsServiceStub.

Comment: I am getting the same Exception..Even after generated files also. Any Help Thanks In Advance